# What regex for replacing shortcodes in wordpress?

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am a regex newbie, but I do have a Regex plugin for wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Here's what I need to search for:
[flickr set=72157627233903733 photo=6]

and here's what I need to replace it with:
[flickr_set id="72157627233903733"]

there are a couple of the shortcodes that look like this: 
[flickr set=72157627532956200 photo=14190577477 size=small align=right hspace=10 vspace=10]

and they need the same replacement: 
[flickr_set id="72157627532956200"]

What's a simple regex to do this?  I basically need to search for [flickr set= and ignore everything after the set id until the closing bracket ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\[flickr[^\]]+set=(\d+).*?\]
```

Comment: I tried it like this: /[flickr[^]]+set=(\d+).*?]/ 
But it didn't find anything.

Comment: You gotta escape the literal brackets.